# How to order app picker alphabetically in 22.04?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, menu

So, the new app picker for Jammy and (presumably) Impish doesn't order apps alphabetically. I've looked up and down `dconf` for this, but couldn't find a way to automatically order the apps alphabetically. Is there a simple fix?

[image: app grid comparison]

Comment: I thought this thing was called the AppGrid.  That's what it's called in the extension menu modules

Comment: I thought this thing was called the App Grid.  That's what it's called in the Extensions Manager / Extensions (configure GNOME shell extensions) package menu modules.  There is one in particular called: Alphabetical App Grid - which alphabetizes upon selection:  https://github.com/mjakeman/extension-manager   https://extensions.gnome.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **Alphabetical App Grid** to alpha sort your apps... https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4269/alphabetical-app-grid/

Use **Favourites in AppGrid** to put your favorites in... https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4485/favourites-in-appgrid/

**Note**: Keep in mind that these gnome-extensions may not be compatible with Gnome 4.2.

Answer (score 2):

Run following on terminal then log out and log in again to see changes:

```sh
gsettings set org.gnome.shell app-picker-layout "[]"
```

Alternatively, you can put value `[]` on `app-picker-layout` of `org/gnome/shell` using dconf-editor.

Comment: Wow! Amazingly simple!